# XHR ontimeout triggering only on new ipads

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, xmlhttprequest

I have an intranet site that has been working for years on ipads. It uses XHR to poll and live update the site for the users. Recently bought the new ipad air 2s and the site is no longer functioning. On the older ipads and my desktop browser it works fine, but on the new ipads it randomly calls the xhr.ontimeout. Console debugging shows very different results between the two. On the old ipads and on desktop the console debugging is as expected and everything is in order and then I look at the one from the ipad airs and I have no clue what the hell is going on with them. The ipad airs are updated to the latest iOS version.

Additionally, the viewport user-scalable=no works on the old ipads but on the new ipad airs this command is completely ignored and theres nothing I can do to disable double touch zoom.

Here is some code:

```
var XHRrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var XHRresponse;
XHRrequest.onloadend = function (evt) {
  if (XHRresponse=="end") {
   console.log("end request");
  }
  else {
    XHRrequest.open("POST", url, true);
    XHRrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    XHRrequest.send(formData);
  }
 };
XHRrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (XHRrequest.readyState == 4 && XHRrequest.status == 200) {
  XHRresponse = XHRrequest.responseText
 }
};
XHRrequest.ontimeout = function() {
  console.log("Error: event timed out");
 };
XHRrequest.open("POST", url, true);
XHRrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
XHRrequest.send(formData);
```

Comment: you said you checked the console so why not tell us what it said, just for fun.

Comment: Basically the console.log events are repeated and the XHR.readyState is out of order with the ipad airs. It also will return xhr.status=0 while still cycling through the different readystate values.

Comment: are you doing ajax in a loop strcture? you may need a closure

Comment: or are you trying to do synchronus ajax? if so it's deprecated and that may be the cause. you should try to post some code.

Comment: Kind of but not exactly. I have a request run and depending on what is returned it will either run again or terminate. This works 100% fine and has worked 100% fine (still is working fine) for all the older ipads and desktop browsers, but on the new ipad airs it does not. In fact, many times the ontimeout is called on the first request and sometimes safari will just not load at all for the site.

Comment: i doubt anyone will be able to offer much more help without seeing your code.

Comment: I edited and added code

Comment: that's not going to be sufficient for debugging. we need to see how that code is being called. you said it was recursive, show the recusion.

Comment: Updated it with the onloadend and onreadystatechange listeners. Reminder, this code works on everything but the new ipad airs and even then it still works on them but randomly, and frequently, triggers ontimeout or just doesn't load at all.